# Uninstall TCP/IP Windows XP (uninstall is greyed out)

Tags: windows-xp, networking, tcpip

A laptop displays "aquiring network address" continuously for both wired and wireless network connections.  TCP/IP is set to obtain an IP address automatically, and use an automatic DNS address.  DHCP is turned on.  Default settings.

I'd like to reset or reinstall TCP/IP as a possible solution.

Logged in as local administrator, Uninstall is greyed out for TCP/IP of Local Area 
Connection properties.

Tried [this method](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325356), but when trying to install TCP/IP, it is not available; only Microsoft TCP/IP version 6 is, perhaps because Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) remains in the list?  The changes made in the method above have not removed TCP/IP from list in LAN properties.

[Using netsh to reset TCP/IP](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;299357) also doesn't resolve the problem.

Is TCP/IP (v4) software hard-wired into Windows XP?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up re-imaging the laptop.

It's like having to demolish a kitchen in order to change a dishwasher.  Thanks again Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks for the -1, Microsoft employee.  Truth hurts?

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove it, as it's part of Windows.

Try inserting the Windows XP CD and going to *Start*, *Run*, type in `cmd`, press ok, inside the `cmd` console type

```
sfc /scannow
```

and let it check all your system files for corruption.

Comment: How exactly would this scan solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As above, you can't remove it but you *can* reset it:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357

and

http://www.petri.co.il/reinstall_tcp_ip_on_windows_xp.htm

As a last resort you could try the following but I'd recommened the reset route first:

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/reinstall-tcpip-windows/

Comment: Thanks, all of those methods I've tried and linked to above. ;-)